# WPF Multithreading: Dispatcher exception

Tags: dispatcher

i'm new to the WPF and I've noticed that you cannot access directly from another thread to the WPF controls. Instead, you have to use the Dispatcher. I have read some articles and questions from the stackoverflow and still don't know why the next code does not work.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(
        new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
          delegate()
          {
              TransformGroup transform = new TransformGroup();

              RotateTransform rot = new RotateTransform(45);
              TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform(500, 500);


              transform.Children.Add(rot);
              transform.Children.Add(trans);

              bOne.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        new Action(
                          delegate()
                          {
                              bOne.RenderTransform = transform;
                          }
                      ));
                  }
              ));


        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

where the xaml is:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Custom="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008" x:Class="Prueba.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <Custom:SurfaceButton Name="bOne" Content="SurfaceButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Still throwing exception when try to modify bOne.RenderTransform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found, I post here the correct version.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(
        new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
          delegate()
          {


              bOne.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        new Action(
                          delegate()
                          {
                              TransformGroup transform = new TransformGroup();

                              RotateTransform rot = new RotateTransform(45);
                              TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform(100, 100);


                              transform.Children.Add(rot);
                              transform.Children.Add(trans);

                              bOne.RenderTransform = transform;
                          }
                      ));
                  }
              ));


        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

I don't realized that transform has to be inside the invoke.